# Email address from YouTube API?

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am trying to get specific channel details from the YouTube API, i.e. email address connecting to channel, connected social media accounts if available (Facebook, Instagram, Twitter). This would be for channels that have made the info public. I can see the email by going to a channel "About" page, but it would be great to get this directly from the API.
I am trying to build something similar to what you get from Influencer Marketing Platforms on a small business website.
Many thanks in advance.
Mick

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]; then do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any YouTube Data API v3 endpoint existing to retrieve the YouTube channel "About" tab. However by getting the source code of the webpage of the "About" tab of the YouTube channel interesting you, you can grab links with the following python 3 algorithm for instance.

```py
import urllib.request

def getURL(url):
    return urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')

youtuberId = 'UCF_UozwQBJY4WHZ7yilYkjA'
content = getURL('https://www.youtube.com/channel/' + youtuberId + '/about');
parts = content.split('u0026q=')
partsLen = len(parts)
links = []
for partsIndex in range(partsLen):
    part = parts[partsIndex]
    realPart = part.split('\"')[0]
    if realPart[:4] == 'http':
        realPart = realPart.replace('%3A', ':').replace('%2F', '/')
        if not realPart in links:
            links += [realPart]
            print(realPart)
```

For the email if any provided, there isn't any way to retrieve it automatically because a captcha is protecting it to be retrieved with an algorithm.

Note that I gave more details on [this other StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73908946).