# Is it possible to fetch a channel's about info from YouTube API including (email, description etc)?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is it possible to fetch links and email for a channel or a user through API?

[image: See the info I'm looking for here]

I looked at the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/), but could not find it there.

Answer (score 0):

One more time YouTube Data API v3 doesn't provide a basic feature.

I would suggest you to use my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/dbeb1ba53953e89f2a167b2c06dc8a38399259e5/channels.php#L72-L117) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com), indeed by requesting https://yt.lemnoslife.com/channels?part=about&id=CHANNEL_ID you would get a JSON with the channel about info (description, stats, details and links) you are looking for in `item['about']`.

Note that the email can't be retrieved automatically as it is protected by a Google captcha as discussed in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71365699/7123660).

Example of result with the YouTube channel id you shared [`UCp4DtLatjb5dBNHHYcvVXCw`](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCp4DtLatjb5dBNHHYcvVXCw/about):

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
    "etag": "NotImplemented",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "NotImplemented",
            "id": "UCp4DtLatjb5dBNHHYcvVXCw",
            "about": {
                "stats": {
                    "joinedDate": 1258671600,
                    "viewCount": "18004212"
                },
                "description": "FREE Online Piano Lessons, featuring concepts that will greatly assist students in developing a solid and sound technique.  Also, this channel features performances by #1 Classical Billboard artist Josh Wright. For questions or video requests, click the link! Josh also offers private online piano lessons through Skype - for more information about how to join his studio, please email him at josh@joshwrightpiano.com",
                "details": {
                    "location": "United States"
                },
                "links": [
                    {
                        "url": "http:\/\/www.joshwrightpiano.com\/contact",
                        "thumbnail": "https:\/\/encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com\/favicon-tbn?q=tbn:ANd9GcSI6T1qSJhEF6q1lGXjosLrKLn-8LCOIrI-An-Jq4YgPHlWxdASCMOkA-LB_xpHQyUyaZkglhOVCfhsr6XXlqKwQHIHp9vvDUl-rsS2Q7lHmzuUQTBh1E5qQW6i",
                        "title": "CLICK TO ASK JOSH A QUESTION"
                    },
                    ...
                    {
                        "url": "https:\/\/plus.google.com\/u\/0\/117288545879529996393\/posts",
                        "thumbnail": "https:\/\/encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com\/favicon-tbn?q=tbn:ANd9GcQhmnWcjVxlBhv3BZSHT6S8x7H25cC4vVPKESQba14oYS_WiNOyF2zPPJcHWcseS6lKo4DJ9xWOfAYikH-7n8_VWo9tUcEBHB7It5VEbgYZndFDYgk",
                        "title": "CLICK TO JOIN JOSH ON GOOGLE+"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```