# youtube api members map to wordpress users

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a wordpress website that uses woocommerce memberships.
We somehow managed to map patreon users to woocommerce memberships so that they get all the perks via our own website.

I know it's possible to query the Youtube API endpoint `members.list` which would give us 1) the membership level and
2) the youtube channel id of each individual member

How can we then validate that a wordpress user is a youtube valid member?
With patreon the validation is by matching email address, but on youtube there's no access to the user email. I guess the user would have to set his youtube channel id in our website so we can later confirm it matches a valid membership.
The problem is that anyone can provide someone elses channel id to trick the system...

any ideas that would help with this much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would generate a token for each user on your website, such that if they put this token in [their channel description (`ABOUT` tab)](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCv_LqFI-0vMVYgNR3TeB3zQ/about) then you can be sure that the given YouTube channel owns the given account on your website where he got his random token. You can get their channel description by using [this reverse-engineered YouTube UI solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73908946/7123660).

You can also think of other mechanisms such as requiring the user to post a comment on a video and checking using YouTube Data API v3 [`CommentThreads: list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) endpoint or post a message on a livestream and checking using YouTube Live Streaming API [LiveChatMessages: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/list) endpoint.

Note that depending on your token format, it may be useful to use an unusual pattern to put in their channel descriptions to avoid wrong authentication (a channel description containing unintentionally a token assigned to a user by your website). For instance if you assign an id (`0`, `1` and so on) to each user (or if you just use their usernames) just requiring this id to be in the channel description isn't very secure as anyone may put unintentionally someone else token. What you can do while still avoiding random token is to use a prefix. That way your website won't just look for `0`, `1` and so on in their channel description but instead `Your website: 0` or `Your website: 1`... Using a prefix keeps user-friendliness (`Your website: Benjamin Loison` looks better than `77ff716cfdd4e7ed`) while being quite secure.