# About Section Links Using Youtube Data API

Tags: youtube-api

I am trying to fetch 'Links' part in the About Section of a YouTube channel, Please check the image for reference. Is there any API endpoint for that, I have fetched all the channel options like brandingSettings, snippet, contentDetails, status etc but those links are nowhere. Or is there no endpoint for that.

[About Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjLaE.png)

Thanks

Comment: Duplicated with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73904750/7123660).

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminLoison I checked the provided link, Its working